# Karma inserts commas in DOM

Tags: karma-runner

I’m serving an HTML file as “DOM” in Karma:

```js
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      { // Base HTML
          'pattern': './index.html',
          'type': 'dom',
          'watched': false
      }, // …
```

The page shows up in Karma’s DEBUG screen, but each newline has a comma added to it, so, for instance, these lines from `index.html`

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

turn to

```html
<head>,    <meta charset="utf-8">,    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">,    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">,
```

in the compiled HTML.

I received Karma as an NPM package, and the installed version is 4.0.0. Karma itself is at 6.4.1. karma-html2js-preprocessor is at 1.1.0, but I don’t use it, at least explicitly:

```js
    preprocessors: {
    }, //…
```

Why are the commas included and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: What version of Karma do you use?

Comment: It’s 6.4.1. I’ve updated the question with the information. I confused Karma’s version with the NPM package’s.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in the Karma itself. Try creating a new issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues